# Strange VS2013 bug? Or programmer induced disease?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I have a `GameObject` class that inherits from `Object`. Stepping in both their constructors has gone crazy, but the objects are created without a problem. Before someone asks, I'm on a debug build. Let me show you:

**Edit** Since people complained, I will post the actual code, not images.

```
GameObject::GameObject(string name) : Object(name)
{
    // ...
}

Component* GameObject::AddComponent(SharedPtrComponent component)
{
    if (find(components.begin(), components.end(), component) == components.end())
    {
        components.push_back(component);
        return component.get();
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

After the program executes the first line of the `GameObject` constructor (i.e. the `Object` initialization), it skips to the empty line between the brace and `return nullptr` in `AddComponent`.

What's going on?

PS. I tried this on both express and ultimate versions. Exact same stepping sequence. And I tried cleaning etc. The `Object` constructor is acting up likewise. Mm.

**Update:** Ok, maybe this works: here's a minimal project which still exhibits the strange stepping: [VS2013 project](http://rapidshare.com/share/7F2225BC5CBDAF158D4F92D13B5916A8)

Comment: You have been on SO long enough that you don't post pictures of code, you post the actual code *as text*.

Comment: Sure, but that wouldn't work if I want to show the current line being executed.

Comment: You multi-threading? Optimizer on?

Comment: No multithreading, no optimization.

Comment: Does `GetComponent` call `AddComponent`?

Comment: No, and the bug was there before I put that line in there.

Comment: Hmm.  Personally, at that point, I'd try recreating the project under a different name by adding all the source files through Visual Studio, and then copying/pasting the code into them.  I've experienced random issues with Visual Studio which can be fixed by nothing but that.  Sometimes IntelliSense dies, sometimes it just won't build - even after a clean, sometimes you get file corruptions.  It's kind of random.

Comment: [If that doesn't fix the issue](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-06NpQFp-Cc0/T8_cfS3LoFI/AAAAAAAABS4/_8SoBCn-bD0/s1600/throwing-computer.gif)....

Comment: Hahaha, yeah I wish that solved the problem, not that I didn't feel the urge to attempt a solution like that!

Comment: @KristianD'Amato, you shouldn't listen to people who urge you to remove pictures since actual code is useless here. Did you try to remove all the content of Debug folder? Not do the clean build but remove everything by hand

Comment: Yes, I removed everything except the code and headers, and even tried a new project with the old code. The stepping is normal in CodeBlocks.

Comment: Could you post the whole project somewhere? Or it depends on something? It is hard to believe MSVS has a bug in the debugger. I'm using it without any problems. Also you may have some strange behavior if you use some dll which was build for release but you are in debug

Comment: I will try to do so, thanks. I don't understand the downvotes. Isn't this a well asked question?

Comment: It is hard to understand why people do some things sometimes, this is the case I believe :)

Comment: I've tried uploading a sample project. Let me know if you can get it to download and work! Thanks.

Comment: Your project works well. It steps to GameObject::ctor-> Object::ctor -> SetName(name); -> nextID++;. After it jumps to the end `}` of namespace which is visually wrong but I don't see anythign wrong in assembly code

Comment: I've tried it on two machines and in Object::ctor it steps from line 13 directly to 27 (`return objectID`). Doesn't that happen? I'm stumped. Are you using VS2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I believe I understand what is going on here. In short: it is a *visual* bug in MSVS debugger.

Let's find out what is going on: first you create your `GameObject` which consists of the following steps: call parent ctor(`Object`) and call initializers and/or *inline initializers*. You don't have initializers but you have *inline initializer* `GameObject* parent = nullptr;`

And that is exactly why debugger goes `visually crazy` it has to execute initializers which is not right here but in the header instead. I'm not sure why it has this glitch but if you remove inline initializers it will be gone. I suggest to file a bug to the Visual Studio team. It is only a visual bug but still a bug.

Comment: Thanks, then I'm not the only one going crazy :) I removed the initializers and the problem's gone. Must be a bug then.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems when stepping through the code in the debugger, it is often a good idea to switch to disassembly view (`ALT + 8`) and step through there.

You do not have to understand much of the assembly. Just look for `call` instructions and the like. Note that if you step into another function (from the disassembly view `call`) with F11, you can then switch back to the actual source code (if you have it).